# My pictures are not shown in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my work. I have to write Javascript file which will display me a website like this one `http://tinypic.com/r/2iu47b6/8` . I have already given html and css file which am I not allowed to change. List of pictures in JS must be given as array.

I have to write function onInit() which starts after loading the site and creates XHTML code with list of pictures and paste it in cell with ID = "seznam". Other function must work that way when you click on picture it shows up in full size, like you can see on picture in LINK i posted.

Here appears my problem. I created JS file and my pictures doesn't show up when I open html website. If I try to open picture in new tab I get error  `"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"`.

I have html, css and js files saved together in one map, and pictures in subfolder "slike", but my website anyway doesn't work.

Can someone please check my code, and help me? `http://plnkr.co/edit/zD0Chi8WUqLPf1JaKwr2?p=preview`

Thanks!

EDIT: Pictures imported to website are Sample pictures from Windows 7 if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure the pictures are in the correct folder (`slike`), and that your HTML file is in a folder containing the pictures folder?

Comment: This is what shows up when i open my website: http://tinypic.com/r/21eb9qf/8

Comment: Right click on the image and try to use Open in New tab and see if they are in the right path.

Comment: Yep. The pictures aren't being found. What is your folder structure?

Comment: It looks like you may be overloading the print variable with both your string to print and your index.   `print =print+"<img src=\""+print[i]`

Comment: @AndreiBârsan
Here is proof for you: http://tinypic.com/r/11qom4k/8

Comment: Why can't you use a simple jQuery Slider?

Comment: Check out bxSlider's implementation [#1](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1) and [#2](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-2)!!!

Comment: @PraveenKumar we are not allowed to use jQuery yet, because we didn't learned it yet.

Like I said, we have to write function onInit() which starts after loading the site and creates XHTML code with list of pictures and paste it in cell with ID = "seznam". 
Then when you click on picture in that table on HTML website the picture should be displayed in full size.

Comment: Okay.. Got it... `:D`

Comment: And I am not able to change HTML or CSS file! Only Javascript.

Comment: Ah....so this is for class.

Comment: Yes, it is for school, and I managed previous 5 exercises out, but this one doesn't want to work...

Answer (score 0):

Probably this line is the problem:

```
print =print+"<img src=\""+print[i]+"\" onClick=\"ShowPics(this);\" />"
```

It should probably be:

```
print =print+"<img src=\""+pictures[i]+"\" onClick=\"ShowPics(this);\" />"
```

Comment: @M.H. Do you have the pictures on the website? Maybe your URLS should start with "/".

Comment: I have html, css and js files saved together in one map, and pictures in subfolder "slike".
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=11qom4k&s=8#.VKv-_SuG_T8

Comment: @M.H. Add "/" to the beginnig of the picture URLs and try again.

Comment: I doesn't work, HTML is now searching for file:///C:/slike/Tulips.jpeg

Comment: @M.H. Is the HTML file in the same folder?

Comment: Html file is in folder, than pictures are in subfolder named "slike". I posted printscreen of my map, check out; http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=11qom4k&s=8#.VKv-_SuG_T8

Comment: @M.H. So you are working with a local file. Your picture URLs should start with './slike' then.

Comment: I make this code now:
var pictures = new Array("/slike/Chrysanthemum.jpeg","/slike/Tulips.jpeg","/slike/Koala.jpeg","/slike/Penguins.png");

The pictures are still not being found. If I try to open picture in New tab i got this: http://tinypic.com/r/2akjqix/8

Comment: @M.H. Try this:
new Array("./slike/Chrysanthemum.jpeg","./slike/Tulips.jpeg","./slike/Koala.jpeg","./slike/P‌​enguins.png");

Comment: That is the same is i do.

Oh didn't saw the dots.
Still not working.

Comment: @M.H. They start with a dot.

Comment: This is what I got without dots: http://i.imgur.com/waXRRwH.png
This is how my folder with HTML, JS, CSS and "slike" looks: http://i.imgur.com/ga4J0lN.png